# How to turn on iPhone's flash for 1 second?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In the settings for my app, there is a switch allowing the user to turn iPhone's flash on or off (flash is used to indicate certain points in app logic while it's running). What I want to implement is this: when the user toggles this switch on, I want it to, well, flash for a split second to indicate its 'ON' state.

Now, I know how to set `torchMode` on or off - this is implemented in the app itself, but I'm not sure how to correctly make it 'blink' for settings purpose. One of the ways I thought of is to use following code (`toggleFlash()` is a static method for toggling `torchMode` implemented in main code):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    ViewController.toggleFlash(on: true)
}, completion: { (_) in
    ViewController.toggleFlash(on: false)
})
```

This does make it 'blink', but only for a moment - not 1 second. Besides, I'm not so sure if it's at all correct to use `animate` for this purpose. Another idea is to use `Thread.sleep`, but this looks like an even worse practice.

Can someone recommend better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a timer.

```
func flashForOneSecond() {
    ViewController.toggleFlash(on: true)
    flashOffTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1, target:self, selector:#selector(self.switchFlashOff), userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
}

@objc func switchFlashOff() {
    ViewController.toggleFlash(on: false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this:

```
func flash() {
    ViewController.toggleFlash(on: true)
    let time = DispatchWallTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: time) {
        ViewController.toggleFlash(on: false)
    }
}
```

wallDeadline is reliable and the solution is packed in one function.